# Resetting countdown in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want after user typing every time in input run resetting countdown, i add `clearTimeout` but it don't work. What do i do? (Please help me in my code, i don't want new code.)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qySNq/

Html:

```
<input id="MizMah">
<div id="Seconds" style="font-size: 80px;">5</div>​
```

Js code:

```
$('#MizMah').live('keyup', function () {
    function render(n) {
        var digits = [],
            r;
        do {
            r = n % 10;
            n = (n - r) / 10;
            digits.unshift([r].join(''));
        } while (n > 0);
        $('#Seconds').html(digits.join(''));
    }

    (function timer(current) {
        render(current);
        if (current > 0) {
            myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                timer(current - 1);
            }, 1100);
            clearTimeout(myTimeout);
        }
    }(5));
})​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were clearing the timeout right after setting it. Try this:

```
var myTimeout = null;

$('#MizMah').live('keyup', function () {
    function render(n) {
        var digits = [],
            r;
        do {
            r = n % 10;
            n = (n - r) / 10;
            digits.unshift([r].join(''));
        } while (n > 0);
        $('#Seconds').html(digits.join(''));
    }

    (function timer(current) {
        render(current);
        if (current > 0) {
            clearTimeout(myTimeout);
            myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                timer(current - 1);
            }, 1100);
        }
    }(5));

})
```